# How to impersonate an account and start explorer.exe?

Tags: vb.net, impersonation, windows-explorer

I have the following code. Which results in error `The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142). Click OK to close the application.` Can someone tell me what is wrong?

```
        Dim domain, username, passwordStr, remoteServerName As String
        Dim password As New Security.SecureString
        Dim command As New Process

        domain = DBc.GetControlVal(34) 'Domain Name
        username = DBc.GetControlVal(35) 'Network username
        passwordStr = ENDC.DecryptData(DBc.GetControlVal(36)) 'password
        remoteServerName = DBc.GetControlVal(37) 'Remote server Name

        Dim impersonator As New clsAliasAccount(username, passwordStr)

        For Each c As Char In passwordStr.ToCharArray
            password.AppendChar(c)
        Next


        command.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Windows\explorer.exe"
        command.StartInfo.Arguments = "\\" & remoteServerName & "\"

        command.StartInfo.UserName = username
        command.StartInfo.Password = password
        command.StartInfo.Domain = domain
        command.StartInfo.Verb = "open"
        command.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False

        impersonator.BeginImpersonation()
        command.Start()
        impersonator.EndImpersonation()
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but 1. you might want to create a ProcessStartInfo and initialize your Process as `command = new Process(yourPSI)` Then again you are attempting to impersonate a user that may reside on a remote host? That looks fishy. Do you really need impersonation? The 0xc0000142 is commonly associated with a dll initialization failure (such can arise when having insufficiant permissions to access specific dll's)

Comment: Thank you for your time, My application uses some files that resides on a server. So when a user runs the app from his client, if he is not an administrator he will not get access to the files. Which will cause error in the app. He may have to provide administrator credentials manually to gain access. which is not acceptable for the user. To answer your question, No I don't really need impersonation but is there any other way?

Comment: Well eigther you provide the credentials to the impersonator, or to the `ProcessStartInfo`, parhaps doing both causes your problem?